# GoCardless API - List Subscriptions

Tags: php, api, gocardless

I am using the GoCardless Documentation [here](https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#subscriptions-list-subscriptions) to try list all subscriptions for a customer.

I have followed the instructions as you can see below, however nothing at all is displaying when I run this script - does anyone know what I may have done wrong?

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';    
$client = new \GoCardlessPro\Client(array(
  'access_token' => 'XXXXXx',
  'environment'  => \GoCardlessPro\Environment::LIVE
));

     $client->subscriptions()->list([
  "params" => ["customer" => "CU000R3B8512345"]
]);
```

Comment: use something like postman to verify that your request should return data

Comment: @Kevin sorry what is 'postman'?

Comment: You’re just executing a command. You’re not returning or printing anything, so nothing’s going to display.

Comment: @MartinBean - how would I do that Martin? I have tried turning the whole line into a variable and printing it, but that fails too `$result=$client->subscriptions()->list([...`

Comment: Well it depends what you’re trying to do, but `$client->subscriptions()->list()` will probably give you back a result. Capture that in a variable, and either use the resultant value or print it.

Comment: @its a tool for running integration tests on APIs

Comment: @MartinBean - No, `$client->subscriptions()->list()` shows nothing

Comment: Yes, it won’t show anything just calling that method. You need to do something with the result.

Comment: It returns a [Cursor Pagination in JSON](https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#api-usage-cursor-pagination)

Comment: how do i display the result?

Comment: I think you need to read a basic PHP tutorial on working with variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a method on its own doesn’t do anything. It’ll execute the given method, but it’s not going to print anything to your browser screen on its own.

As [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) says (and is documented in GoCardless’s API documentation), calling `$client->subscriptions()->list()` will *return* a [cursor-paginated response](https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#api-usage-cursor-pagination) object. So you need to do something with this result. What that is, I don’t know as it’s your application’s business logic and only you know that.

```php
<?php

use GoCardlessPro\Client;
use GoCardlessPro\Environment;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Client(array(
    'access_token' => 'your-access-token-here',
    'environment' => Environment::SANDBOX,
));

// Assign results to a $results variable
$results = $client->subscriptions()->list([
    'params' => ['customer' => 'CU000R3B8512345'],
]);

foreach ($results->records as $record) {
    // $record is a variable holding an individual subscription record
}
```

Comment: @Designer Did you put anything inside the foreach loop other than the comment placed by Martin?

Comment: It is showing `Catchable fatal error: Object of class GoCardlessPro\Core\ListResponse could not be converted to string i`

Comment: @Designer - `echo"<pre>$record</pre>";` you will see the result!

Comment: Try a `print_r($record);` that will show you what the object looks like so you can then use the actual properties

Comment: @Designer A couple of times it’s been said now that calling that method will _return_ an object. **It will not print anything to the screen**. _You_ have to do something with the object that’s returned!

Answer (score 0):

Pagination with Gocardless:

```
function AllCustomers($client)
{
    $list = $client->customers()->list(['params'=>['limit'=>100]]);
    $after = $list->after;
    // DO THINGS
    print_r($customers);

    while ($after!="")
    {
        $customers = $list->records;
        // DO THINGS
        print_r($customers);
        
        // NEXT
        $list = $client->customers()->list(['params'=>['after'=>$after,'limit'=>100]]);
        $after = $list->after;
    }
}
```